# Deletion of multiple characters inside of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, translate, strip

i want the string 'abc'

```
abc="['one']"\n['two']"
```

to output

```
one 
two
```

as far as i know:

`.strip()`  only replaces characters at the beginning and at the ending of the string

`.translate()`  only takes one variable

`.replace()` only works with 1 character.

Comment: ".replace() only works with 1 character." Nope, it works with strings with any number of characters. `x.replace("hello I am a very long string", "yes I am also very long as well")` is just as valid as `x.replace("X", "Y")`

Comment: yes.I wanted to say it can only replace 1 thing to another be it a string or a character

Comment: You really need to clarify exactly which characters you're trying to replace - are you wanting to keep all alphas and carriage returns, or are you wanting to remove all brackets and quotes, or are your requirements something else entirely?

Comment: I don't understand what `abc` actually contains; `abc="['one']"\n['two']"` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re`.

```
import re
abc = re.sub(r"['\[\]]", '', abc)
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i sort of fixed the problem by

```
abcd=abc.replace("['","")
abcdf=abcd.replace("']","")
```

not a perfect solution but it works

Comment: You can of course omit the intermediate `abdc` by using `abc.replace("['","").replace("']","")`, but the other answer using `re.sub` is nicer anyway.